# Utilizing Inheritance to Print a Reference

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, extends

I'm having issues on as how to call variables from multiple areas of code to print an ArrayList here is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReferenceHolder extends java.lang.Object{
ArrayList<Reference> references = new ArrayList<Reference>();



public void printAllBibtexEntries() {
    Reference.getBibtexEntry(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addReference(Book book ) {
    String author = Reference.getAuthor();
    System.out.println(references.size());
    references.add(new Book(author, null, null, 0));
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void addReference(Article article) {
    references.add(new Article(null, null, 0, null, 0, 0));
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

}
```

The issue is that I want to call variables from a "Book" and "Article" class, utilize that information from the "addReference" methods and print the information via the printAllBibtexEntries methods. Any hints on how I can print from BibtexEntries variables instead of null?

P.S: Even if I did insert the variables within the references.add(), it'll still return "null." The example being in the addReference(Book book) pertaining to "author."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface or an abstract class for Books/Articles

for example:

```
interface IReference {
     public String getAuthor();
}

class Book implements IReference {
    ... implement the interface
}

class Article implements IReference {
    ... implement the interface
}
```

so now you can declare your list as:

```
ArrayList<IReference> references = new ArrayList<IReference>();
```

and

```
public void printAllBibtexEntries() {
    IReference ref = (IReference)Reference.getBibtexEntry(null, null, null, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(ref.getAuthor());
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```